# C++ program return code when std::terminate is called in thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, bash, c++11, exit-code

I have a program that creates that uses `std::thread` objects to perform work concurrently. I'm calling the program from a bash script and want to stop the script if the program does not terminate with `EXIT_SUCCESS`. I've encountered a rather non-intuitive behavior in the following situation: one of the threads throws an exception (thus calling `std::terminate`), leading to complete program termination. However, the program's return code is `EXIT_SUCCESS` (instead of some error code, which I would expect). Why is that?

I know that using `std::thread` is not a clever idea in many cases and I plan to move to `std::async` (or the like), but at the moment, I'm interested in a quick solution to that.

Comment: It's your program.  You have complete control over its exit status.

Comment: Can you show MCVE ?

Comment: It should be doing this (`std::terminate` calls `std::abort`): _"Implementation defined status is returned to the host environment that indicates unsuccessful execution."_ we need [mcve] + platform details. see: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/abort

Answer (score 1):

Well, consider me stupid. The program properly returns an error code, but as I piped the output (it writes a lot of log) into `tee`, the return code stored in `$?` is probably the one of `tee`, which exits without failure.

[EDIT] I'm using `PIPESTATUS` now to get the correct exit code.

Comment: Consider yourself smart instead :) You figured out the real cause of the problem by carefully examining what you were doing.

Answer (score 1):

As Richard Critten has pointed out in the comment `std::terminate()` calls `std::abort()`, but that's not all.

C++ offers quite a few mechanisms to control such situations. The one I can suggest is the following:

Register your own handler for calls of `std::terminate()` using the [`std::set_terminate()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/set_terminate):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <exception>

int main()
{
    std::set_terminate
    ( []()
      { 
        std::cout << "Unhandled exception\n";
        std::exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
      }
    );

    throw 1;
}
```

Calling [`std::exit()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/exit) causes normal program termination with some cleanup steps.

Another alternative would be to register the [`SIGABORT`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/abort) handler and exit the program with desired exit code. But in that case no resource clean-up is done.

Answer (score 0):

C++11 has the `exception_ptr` type that allows to transport exceptions between threads. So in the case if you want to handle exceptions you can consider the following approach.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<thread>
#include<exception>
#include<stdexcept>

static std::exception_ptr eptr = nullptr;

void foo()
{
    try
    {
        ....
        throw std::runtime_error("Bla bla"); // put your exception instead of runtime_error
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        eptr = std::current_exception();
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    std::thread t(foo);
    t.join();

    if (eptr)
    {
        try
        {
            std::rethrow_exception(eptr);
        }
        catch(const std::exception &ex)
        {
            std::cerr << "Thread exited: " << ex.what() << "\n";
            return EXIT_FAILURE;

        }
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

This method makes sure that the program will exit with the status `EXIT_FAILURE` if the thread throws an exception.